# iOS 7 UINavigationBar not hidden while view transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have view controller transition like vc1 -> vc2 -> vc1. And I need the UINavigationBar be hidden in vc1, and showing in vc2.

I do the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

In iOS6, it works fine. But in iOS7, when I back to vc2 from vc1, the navigation bar is not hidden but moved upward behind the status bar, the bar got hidden after the transition animation finished.

How can I really hide the nav bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];  
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO]; 
}
```

or try like this :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. using [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated] works!

Answer (score 0):

In VC2 Controller put this in - viewDidLoad

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

In VC1 controller put this in -ViewDidLoad

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

then VC1 add this also

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

I hope it will be helpful for you...